# node, npm error os x $PATH

Tags: node.js, npm

Installed npm and nodejs and then installed grunt, ionic, and also the bower, just when I'm going to run any command to use the grunt ...

he says that does not exist (zsh: command not found: grunt)

this is happening after I installed OSX el capitan

and when I put --> npm ls
result /
/
└── (empty)

someone could help me?

Comment: Where was `grunt` installed?